# Link to TOC is broken

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I have the problem that the links back to my TOC do not work properly. The links to all the chapters seem to work fine but if I want to go back I just end up somewhere in the Abstract. How can this be fixed?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\selectlanguage{british}

\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum\lipsum
\newpage\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
\markboth{}{}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}\listoffigures\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}\listoftables\newpage

\markboth{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\chapter{Abbreviations}\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}
Some text\newpage\cleardoublepage

\chapter{One}
Some text\newpage\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Two}
Some text\newpage\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Three}
Some text\newpage\cleardoublepage

\end{document}enter code here
```

Comment: what do you mean by "going back"? How do you try to do this? There are no links to the toc in your example.

Comment: I mean when I hit the back button in the PDF viewer. Dang. I never thought about this being an issue of the viewer and not the PDF itself. Is this a problem on the viewer side or should a link be provided by the PDF that the viewer is referring to? I am using the document viewer in Ubuntu. I am going to test another one to see if it behaves differently.

Comment: Yeah Firefox behaves differently. If I hit the previous button I just end up on another seemingly random page. I also tested another document. Is this something that is taken care of by the viewer and why is this feature so poorly implemented? I have never realized this before.

Comment: I can't tell you why your viewer doesn't handle this correctly, but yes this is a viewer question not a tex question.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you very much for your response! It is not nice the way it is but it seems to be out of my control.

Comment: The behavior of the history/back button in Evince is known to be unintuitive, see for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1045491/.